# How to link librsync (which might have used libtool)

Tags: c, libtool, pkg-config, librsync

Just installed librsync using `apt-get install librsync-dev` on ubuntu. I can link other libraries like this `pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0` but I can't find `librsync` using `pkg-config`. How can I link it?

**UPDATE:** I very new to C and all this compiling linking stuff. Just learned how to find and link using pkg-config. But this librsync seems to be developed using different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with C. The problem is most likely due to librsync NOT providing a package config file. Try:

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep -i rsync
```

If you get no response, librsync has no pkgconfig file available to the system. Instead of using `pkg-config` to link librsync, just add `-lrsync` to your `gcc` command line. E.g.:

```
gcc -Wall -o mynewprog mynewprog.c -lrsync
```